# Post-hoc hardship to avoid early withdrawal penalty (US)

Tags: taxes, ira, penalty, children

My wife and I took money out of our retirement accounts to pay for emergency repairs to our home in May of 2021. Unfortunately, we were not *ordered* to relocate or demolish, so it doesn't meet criteria of IRC 165. However, we also had a child in Aug of 2021, i.e. 4 months after the initial withdrawal. I understand in 2021 families were allowed to withdraw up to $5,000 per child per parent without penalty.

Is it possible to post-hoc request a separate 1099R or explain this situation in my tax return to avoid the additional 10% penalty on that portion of money we withdrew?

Comment: I'd argue that is is reasonable to know 4 months before birth that you're going to have a child... Whether it's going to stand at audit is between you, your attorney/CPA and the Revenue Agent.

Comment: What kind of "retirement account" is this?

Comment: @user102008 it's a traditional 401k, I've taken unpenalized deductions before and understand that the 20% withholding is mandatory and is taxed as income. There is the additional case of the 10% penalty however that I'm concerned about.